# JQuery and accessing nested input element's value of a blog post

Tags: jquery, blogs

I'm working on a blog of my own something like a facebook clone of some sort. I need to make it possible to delete some posts and what I plan to do, is inserting into each post, a hidden (not hidden yet) input with the post id. So I have a big string for each post which goes like this:

```
    $('#blog').append('<div class="blogPost"><div class="postTitre">' +title + '</div>' + 
                          '<div class="postDescription">' + description + '</div>' + 
                          '<div class="postTimeStamp">' + timestamp + '</div>' + 
                          '<embed class="embedPDF" src="./uploads/' + name + '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0"/>' + 
                          '<div class="closeDelete">
                              <input type="text" name="txtID" readonly="readonly" value="' + id + '" />X
                              <div class="close-text">DELETE</div>' +
                          '</div>
                       </div>');
```

I need to access the inner input type named txtID which will be hidden.

I tried a lot of stuff to get that to work, but none is doing what I want. Rigth now, I have this code which uses event delegation, but not sure about how to get the value of my text input:

```
            //THIS WILL FIRE THE DELETE POST EVENT
            $("#blog").on("click", "div.closeDelete", function(){
                var id = $("div.closeDelete").find("input[name=txtID]").val();
                alert("close delete this: " + id + " post");
            });
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You're close... `this` will be the clicked `div.closeDelete` ;)

Comment: I generate various blogPost classed divs and inside them, also generating div.closeDelete with ID inside the input. Need to recover the value of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` will be the clicked `div.closeDelete`
Just use it to find the corresponding id

```
var id = $(this).find('input[name="txtID"]').val();  // instead of $("div.closeDelete").find(...)
```

```js
$("#blog").on("click", "div.closeDelete", function() {
  var id = $(this).find('input[name="txtID"]').val();
  console.log("close delete this: " + id + " post");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog">
  <div class="blogPost">
    <div class="postTitre">title</div>
    <div class="closeDelete">
      <input type="text" name="txtID" readonly="readonly" value="123" />X
      <div class="close-text">DELETE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost">
    <div class="postTitre">title</div>
    <div class="closeDelete">
      <input type="text" name="txtID" readonly="readonly" value="342" />X
      <div class="close-text">DELETE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost">
    <div class="postTitre">title</div>
    <div class="closeDelete">
      <input type="text" name="txtID" readonly="readonly" value="486" />X
      <div class="close-text">DELETE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```